# Using ggplot, how does plot the type lines in legend?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Let's suppose that I have the following dataset

```
Date_spill<-rev(seq(as.Date("2019-02-28"), length = 3135, by = "-1 day"))
Total_var<-data.frame(Total_H1=runif(3135, min=0.5, max = 0.7), Total_H7=runif(3135, min=0.6, max = 0.8), Total_H30=runif(3135, min=0.5, max = 0.8))
CPM_period<-data.frame(x= Date_spill[c(702, 702, 1402, 1402)], 
y=c(10, max(Total$Total_H7), max(Total$Total_H7), 10),
period=c("a", "a", "a", "a"))
```

I want to plot a graph that combines different information. For that reason, each line has a specific color and type. My problem is that using the following code:

```
library(ggplot2)

Graph<-ggplot()+
  theme_test() +
  geom_vline(xintercept= Date_spill[667 ], linetype=4)+ #salida swanbank_B
  geom_vline(xintercept= Date_spill[1630], linetype=3, color="turquoise4", size=0.8)+ # NEM
  geom_vline(xintercept= Date_spill[2900], linetype=1, color="yellow4")+ #Blackout and higher demand
  geom_line(aes(x= Date_spill, y = Total_var$Total_H1, color="Total_var$Total_H1"), linetype="dashed", alpha=0.5 )+
  geom_line(aes(x= Date_spill, y = Total_var$Total_H7, color="Total_var$Total_H7"), linetype="solid", alpha=0.8)+
  geom_line(aes(x= Date_spill, y = Total_var$Total_H30, color="Total_var$Total_H30"), linetype="twodash", alpha = 0.5)+
  scale_color_manual(values = c("darkseagreen3", "skyblue3", "firebrick3"), labels= c("Forecast horizon H = 2", "Forecast horizon H = 7", "Forecast horizon H = 30"))+
  coord_cartesian(expand=c(0,0), ylim = c(10, 60)) +
  geom_polygon(aes(x=CPM_period$x, y=CPM_period$y), colour="gray", alpha=0.2)+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45), legend.position = c(.80, .80)) +
  scale_x_date(breaks = seq(min(Date_spill), max(Date_spill), by="6 month"), date_labels = "%Y - %m")+
  labs(x = "", y="Aggregated Index",color = NULL, fill = NULL)
```

The type of lines in the legend is not the type defined for each time series.
[image]

What would be an option for getting the type lines in the legend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making things harder for yourself because you are not mapping the aesthetics like linetype and color to variables in your data frame. You can try the following modifications (I have had to modify your data slightly as well because your dummy data did not fit inside the plot boundaries you had set)

Note that it is much easier to map to an aesthetic if your data is in long format (rather than the wide format in your example). We can easily swap that round with `tidyr::pivot_longer`

```r
df <- tidyr::pivot_longer(Total_var, -1)

ggplot(df, aes(x = Date_spill, y = value, color = name, linetype = name)) + 
  geom_line() +
  geom_vline(xintercept = Date_spill[667 ], linetype = 4) + 
  geom_vline(xintercept = Date_spill[1630], linetype = 3, 
             color = "turquoise4", size = 0.8) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = Date_spill[2900], 
             linetype = 1, color = "yellow4") + 
  geom_polygon(aes(x = x, y = y), data = CPM_period, colour = "gray", 
               alpha = 0.2, inherit.aes = FALSE) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("darkseagreen3", "skyblue3", "firebrick3"), 
                     labels = c("Forecast horizon H = 2", 
                                "Forecast horizon H = 7", 
                                "Forecast horizon H = 30")) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = 1:3, 
                     labels = c("Forecast horizon H = 2", 
                                "Forecast horizon H = 7", 
                                "Forecast horizon H = 30")) +
  scale_x_date(breaks = seq(min(Date_spill), max(Date_spill), by = "6 month"), 
               date_labels = "%Y - %m") +
  coord_cartesian(expand = 0, ylim = c(0.5, 1)) +
  theme_test() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1), 
        legend.position = c(.80, .80),
        legend.title = element_blank()) +
  labs(x = "", y = "Aggregated Index")
```

[image]

---

**Data used**

```r
Date_spill <- rev(seq(as.Date("2019-02-28"), 
                      length = 3135, by = "-1 day"))

Total_var  <- data.frame(Date_spill,
                         Total_H1  = runif(3135, 0.5, 0.7), 
                         Total_H7  = runif(3135, 0.6, 0.8), 
                         Total_H30 = runif(3135, 0.5, 0.8))

CPM_period <- data.frame(x = Date_spill[c(702, 702, 1402, 1402)],
                         y = c(0.5, Inf, Inf, 0.5),
                         period = c("a", "a", "a", "a"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Is is important to understand, that plotting especially with ggplot2 works with data table in long format, while your total is in wide format.
So first we have to add the date to the table `Total$date_spill = Date_spill` and then to transform it to long format

```
library(reshape2)
total.long = melt(Total, id.vars = "date_spill")
```

then your plotting could be based on this

```
ggplot()+
  theme_test() +
  geom_vline(xintercept= Date_spill[667 ], linetype=4)+ #salida swanbank_B
  geom_vline(xintercept= Date_spill[1630], linetype=3, color="turquoise4", size=0.8)+ # NEM
  geom_vline(xintercept= Date_spill[2900], linetype=1, color="yellow4")+ #Blackout and higher demand
  geom_line(data = total.long, aes(x= date_spill, y = value, group = variable, color=variable,linetype=variable), alpha=0.5 )+
  scale_color_manual(values = c("darkseagreen3", "skyblue3", "firebrick3"), labels= c("Forecast horizon H = 2", "Forecast horizon H = 7", "Forecast horizon H = 30"))+
  scale_linetype_manual(values=c(2,4,6), labels= c("Forecast horizon H = 2", "Forecast horizon H = 7", "Forecast horizon H = 30"))
```

Your MWE is a bit erroneous, so the rest produces garbage. But I think you got the idea.